# why is qtsettings storing floats in a weird mode, what am missing?

Tags: qt

am trying to create a settings file like:

> [graph] weight=3.154
>
> [ui] color=#00FFC1

but am getting something like

> [graph] weight=@Variant(\0\0\0\x87@]/\x1b)
>
> [ui] color=#00FFC1

my code is simple and looks like

```
QSettings settings("foo.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
settings.beginGroup("graph");
settings.setValue("weight", 3.456f);
settings.endGroup();
settings.beginGroup("ui");
settings.setValue("color", "#00FFC1");
settings.endGroup();
settings.sync();
```

qt5.7.1 for linux 64bits

Comment: guess he had a typo since I see 3.154 and 3.456f. Going to the problem I think you know that when 3.456f is placed is only an inaccurate representation of the floating number (IEEE-754) so not to lose information when retrieving it, the bits are saved, they are not saved as a string that eliminates the precision, if you want to save with the *decimals visible* then convert it to QString

Answer (score 3):

You are not really missing anything. All you see is how Qt encodes INI-Files. Since there is no standard describing how certain types should be represented in an INI-File, Qt defined their own. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#Format-enum for more details. In short, any "special" type is represented by `@<typename>(<data>)`, with most of them beeing further encoded as `QVariant`, for which the data you see is `@Variant(<metaTypeId><data>)`. The metatype id for float is 8, or `\0\0\0\x8` encoded as 32-bit hex string. All the stuff after those 4 characters is the actual binary data, as `QDataStream::operator<<` would produce it. However, to make INI-Files at least somewhat readable and compatible to those written by other applications, some types (like `QString`, `int`, `double`, `bool`, ...) use a different, more commonly known representation.

For this concrete case, they decided to not program such an encoding exception for the `float` type. The exact reason is unknown to me, but my personal guess would be that they wanted to make it possible to tell the difference between doubles and floats in the INI-Files, so someone does not accidentily interpret a float as double (and thus assume a given number has double precision, even though it has not).